# Formal and distanced way of saying sorry for replying late, but I was busy

Tags: phrase-requests

In short, someone wrote an apology to me, I saw it and decided to wait until my life became less hectic before replying.

I don't appreciate the apology as I view the motive of the apology to be for the benefit of the writer -- the apology is to help the writer cope with his/her conscience and not for my well-being.

Although I view the apology as insincere, I like to preface my reply by apologizing for responding a month later. What is the most suitable way of apologizing for the late response in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion Based. But you could just reply, "Sorry. Just got around to this. Thanks."

Comment: I refused to participate in Victorian era formality about 50 years ago.  I just tell the truth, if it hurts then that's fine, because it's the truth. Many people cringe at the truth; but in the end, it's the fire we need to burn up all ambiguity and misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Formal:

**I apologize for replying this late.**

Informal:

**Sorry for the belated response.**

Insulting:

**Please excuse the lateness of this response. I was very busy all this time; had far more important things to do. You're a miserable moron. Your guilt means exactly nothing to me. Why don't you stick it up your ass: your head has been getting lonely up there.**

Condescending:

**I'm sorry: I should have replied sooner. You don't need to apologize: you did what you did because that is what you are and therefore blameless.**

Christian-spirited:

**Please forgive me for responding so late. It was chivalrous of you to apologize to me: I certainly appreciate both the apology and the effort, and I admire you. Let's have a drink sometime: my treat.**

Comment: The options you posted are interesting. I'll ponder on it for another week.

Comment: @user59768 Whether intended or not, I think your comment to Ricky reveals some important information necessary to answer your question: “**I’d have responded earlier, but you know me and my procrastinative tendencies.**” (To go full-blown formal, you could consider just ditching the contraction: “**I would** have responded earlier, but you know me and my procrastinative tendencies,” but don't ponder it too much longer!)

Answer (score 0):

***I apologize for my tardy response/reply***.

***Please forgive my tardy reply***.

***Please forgive the tardiness of my reply***.

> tardy:  delayed beyond the expected or proper time :  late [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tardy)

Answer (score 0):

> Apologies for the lateness of my response.

This is more formal and distanced (at least to my eyes) than either "I apologise" or "Please forgive", as the other answerers have suggested.